# Phoenix hbase java.util.concurrent.CancellationException error

Tags: java, php, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have used batch process to execute some opration on hbase table using phoenix every 2 seconds and that is reflect on web admin dashboard but I when I am trying to check on dashbard then sometime I am getting this error.

```
 [response] => error
    [exceptions] => Array
        (
            [0] => java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.create(JdbcResultSet.java:98)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.jdbc.JdbcMeta.execute(JdbcMeta.java:867)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.LocalService.apply(LocalService.java:268)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$ExecuteRequest.accept(Service.java:1024)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$ExecuteRequest.accept(Service.java:1000)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AbstractHandler.apply(AbstractHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.JsonHandler.apply(JsonHandler.java:52)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.server.AvaticaJsonHandler.handle(AvaticaJsonHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:111)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:808)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:714)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.MergeSortResultIterator.getMinHeap(MergeSortResultIterator.java:72)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.MergeSortResultIterator.minIterator(MergeSortResultIterator.java:93)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.MergeSortResultIterator.next(MergeSortResultIterator.java:58)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseGroupedAggregatingResultIterator.next(BaseGroupedAggregatingResultIterator.java:64)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.DelegateResultIterator.next(DelegateResultIterator.java:44)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.OffsetResultIterator.next(OffsetResultIterator.java:45)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.DelegateResultIterator.next(DelegateResultIterator.java:44)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.LimitingResultIterator.next(LimitingResultIterator.java:47)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixResultSet.next(PhoenixResultSet.java:778)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.frame(JdbcResultSet.java:133)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.create(JdbcResultSet.java:91)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:766)
    ... 28 more

        )
```

Each Batch Process it will take 30 records from table and update some information in table. I have used php json API to fetch records from HBase using phoenix. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.